# Plot Distance from two Input boxes to Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, autocomplete

How can I use two input boxes that autocompletes two different latitude/longitude points and have that plotted on a Google Maps using the latest API?

Suppose I have the JS below so far

```
var data = {
    "LAX": {
        "t": "33.9416",
        "g": "118.4085",
        "n": "Los Angeles International Airport"
    },
        "JFK": {
        "t": "40.6413",
        "g": "73.7781",
        "n": "John F. Kennedy International Airport"
    },
        "BWI": {
        "t": "39.1774",
        "g": "76.6684",
        "n": "Baltimore–Washington International Airport"
    }
};

function getAirports() {
    var arr = [];
    for (airport in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(airport)) {
            arr.push(airport + " - " + data[airport].n);
        }
    }
    window.console&&console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}
$("#origin").autocomplete({
    source: getAirports(),
    select: function (event, ui) {
      var value = ui.item.value;
      var airport = data[value.split(" -")[0]];
      $("#output1").html(value+"<br>t:"+airport.t+"<br>t:"+airport.g); 
    }
});
$("#destination").autocomplete({
    source: getAirports(),
    select: function (event, ui) {
      var value = ui.item.value;
      var airport = data[value.split(" -")[0]];
      $("#output2").html(value+"<br>t:"+airport.t+"<br>t:"+airport.g); 
    }
});
```

And I also have an origin and destination input boxes in HTML below

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="origin">Origin:</label>
    <input id="origin">
</div>
    <div id="output1"></div>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="destination">Destination:</label>
    <input id="destination">
</div>
    <div id="output2"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

What is the best way for the two locations to be plotted to Google Maps API **with the submit button click**?

Thanks

Edit:

I want to either use the Distance Matrix API that's implemented in the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) or something like the Directions example used [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions) but I do not really know how to implement either of those with the input boxes that I want to use.

Comment: check [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions)

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, I've looked at that before but what I want is for my data set to be the only list of options for the input boxes' autocomplete and I'm not sure how to easily do that with the example given in the link.

Comment: I don't see any Google Maps API code (or any other Google Maps stuff) in your question.  How are you planning on creating the map?

Comment: The posted HTML is invalid, there are two divs with id="ouput"

Comment: @geocodezip I wan to use Google Maps API but don't really know where to begin other than copying the code in the link that I put in the edit. Also, I've fixed the HTML for the id="output".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions service can't find directions between those locations (the have the wrong sign on the longitude for the names associated with them).

If you want to create a map and add directions, you need to write code to do that, the [example in the documentation is a good starting place](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/r3hd24fn/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var originCoords;
var destCoords;
var markerOrigin, markerDest;
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplay;

function initialize() {
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  $("#origin").autocomplete({
    source: getAirports(),
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var value = ui.item.value;
      var airport = data[value.split(" -")[0]];
      $("#output1").html(value + "<br>t:" + airport.t + "<br>g:" + airport.g);
      originCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(airport.t), parseFloat(airport.g));
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    }
  });
  $("#destination").autocomplete({
    source: getAirports(),
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var value = ui.item.value;
      var airport = data[value.split(" -")[0]];
      $("#output2").html(value + "<br>t:" + airport.t + "<br>g:" + airport.g);
      destCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(airport.t), parseFloat(airport.g));
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay)
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var data = {
  "LAX": {
    "t": "33.9416",
    "g": "-118.4085",
    "n": "Los Angeles International Airport"
  },
  "JFK": {
    "t": "40.6413",
    "g": "-73.7781",
    "n": "John F. Kennedy International Airport"
  },
  "BWI": {
    "t": "39.1774",
    "g": "-76.6684",
    "n": "Baltimore–Washington International Airport"
  }
};

function getAirports() {
    var arr = [];
    for (airport in data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(airport)) {
        arr.push(airport + " - " + data[airport].n);
      }
    }
    window.console && console.log(arr);
    return arr;
  }
  // from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
  if ((originCoords instanceof google.maps.LatLng) && (destCoords instanceof google.maps.LatLng)) {
    if (!markerOrigin || !markerOrigin.setPosition) {
      markerOrigin = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: originCoords
      })
    } else {
      markerOrigin.setPosition(originCoords)
    }
    if (!markerDest || !markerDest.setPosition) {
      markerDest = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: destCoords
      })
    } else {
      markerDest.setPosition(destCoords)
    }
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    bounds.extend(originCoords);
    bounds.extend(destCoords);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    directionsService.route({
      origin: originCoords,
      destination: destCoords,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="origin">Origin:</label>
  <input id="origin">
</div>
<div id="output1"></div>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="destination">Destination:</label>
  <input id="destination">
</div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```